# Is a negative COVID test required for a domestic flight to Newark Liberty International Airport?

Tags: covid-19, ewr

I've been searching for this but haven't found a straight answer.

I have both vaccines, and I'll be traveling to Newark Liberty International Airport next month.

Will EWR airport (or anyone else within the airport, airline, etc..) require a negative COVID test to leave the airport? Is proof of vaccination good enough?

Answer (score 1):

New Jersey doesn't have any special criteria outside of recommendations for domestic travelers

> Unvaccinated individuals who do travel should get tested 1-3 days before their trip and 3-5 days after travel. Even if they test negative, the CDC recommends unvaccinated individuals stay home and self-quarantine for 7 days after domestic travel, and for 10 days if they are unable to test.

> Fully vaccinated individuals and those who have recovered from COVID-19 in the past 3 months do not need to get tested or self-quarantine after travel. However, the CDC recommends fully vaccinated individuals self-monitor for COVID-19 symptoms, and isolate and get tested if they develop symptoms.

> Source : [NJ COVID Site](https://covid19.nj.gov/faqs/nj-information/travel-and-transportation/are-there-travel-restrictions-to-or-from-new-jersey)

But, some states may have different rules in place

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsfI haven't heard of them, but a state could have _departure_ guidelines or rules even for domestic flights. You should find out, or reveal the state of your departure.

Comment: Which states require a Covid test for domestic flights? Hawaii requires it if you’re unvaccinated but that’s it. I’d remove the last paragraph.

Comment: @JonathanReez Hawaii is the only one I know of. So far.