# US Domestic Flights requiring covid tests?

Tags: usa, air-travel, covid-19, domestic-travel

I haven’t flown domestically in such a long time probably over three years. I am wondering i plan to take spirit airlines in early April and go from Michigan to Orlando Florida. My wife and I are both vaccinated and my 13 year old is as well (both doses of pfizer). My two youngest six and seven have not been vaccinated. Do flights require negative proof or anything like that?

Comment: [This question, answer, and comments](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/171452/is-a-negative-covid-test-required-for-a-domestic-flight-to-newark-liberty-intern) might be useful. As noted there in comments, Hawaii is the only US state (so far) to impose covid-specific flight requirements. If you're really nervous, call the airline and ask.

Answer (score 5):

> Do flights require negative proof or anything like that?

Not at the moment (other than Hawaii). But of course, no one knows yet what April will be like.