# Does Delta require covid test before domestic flight?

Tags: usa, covid-19, domestic-travel, delta-air-lines

Looking at flying Delta SEA-SAN in late April.  Reading through some Delta web pages it is clear that Delta requires negative test before international flights to the US (or I guess the US requires it), however I can't find anything that mentions domestic flights.

Does Delta require negative test before domestic flights?

We are not US citizens/residents.

Comment: I can't prove a negative but have never heard of any US airline requiring a test before any domestic flight.

Comment: Here's a [similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/171452/is-a-negative-covid-test-required-for-a-domestic-flight-to-newark-liberty-intern).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: typically no but sometimes yes. It depends on the route + your vaccination status + flight date. No need for SEA-SAN.

---

Long answer:

See https://www.delta.com/us/en/travel-planning-center/know-before-you-go/travel-requirements-guide

> U.S. citizens and residents traveling between destinations within the 48 contiguous United States and Alaska are not subject to entry requirements (Hawaii, Puerto Rico, and the U.S. Virgin Islands may have requirements). Plan your next domestic trip now using our **[Delta Discover Map](https://www.delta.com/us/en/travel-planning-center/find-your-destination/explore-top-destinations?prnt=51302)**.

The [Delta Discover Map](https://www.delta.com/us/en/travel-planning-center/find-your-destination/explore-top-destinations?prnt=51302) is convenient to see the COVID test requirements (and it doesn't mention the "U.S. citizens and residents" criterion), e.g. no need for COVID test for an SFO/LAX/SAN->SEA or SEA->SFO/LAX/SAN flight:

[image]

but one needs for a COVID test for a SEA->HNL flight if before March 27 + not vaccinated.

Comment: Thanks.  You raise a key point (that I didn't realise might be relevant) - your quote says "U.S. citizens and residents traveling between destinations within the 48 contiguous United States..." however we are not US citizens or residents.  Do you think that will make a difference?

Comment: @Midavalo Good point, I don't think so, esp. as https://www.delta.com/us/en/travel-planning-center/find-your-destination/explore-top-destinations?prnt=51302 doesn't mention the "U.S. citizens and resident" criterion. But personally I only have first hand experience as a US resident for SEA<-->SFO/OAK with Delta.

Comment: @Midavalo I’ve flown this exact route during the peak of Omicron and I can assure you that no test is required for non-citizens. And it’s possible that even a mask would not be required on this flight as the mask regulation expires on April 18 :)